# Enable static links in JQuery Cycle

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I'm using the newest version of JQuery Cycle, taking advantage of the custom pagerAnchorBuilder function like so:

```
pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
    // return selector string for existing anchor 
    return '#nav li:eq(' + idx + ')';
```

Those list items under #nav are also tied into a Jquery Accordion so when you click on them, a larger background image changes and the accordion drops down to reveal content.

Inside that content I have text links, but they don't work, not sure why, any ideas would be awesome. Thank you!

Comment: Can you isolate the issue a little more?   It sounds like you might just have a problem with Accordion.  Is your issue that, once the Accordion expands, there is content in there and the links in the content don't work?  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6jcck/) is an example of what I am talking about.  If you click the GOOGLE link, and then look at your 'Developer Tools' you will see the error:

    "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options."

Comment: The links work when just the accordion is active. When I enable the cycle is when they break because I think the cycle is trying to recognize any <a> tags within and use them for the navigation to change slides.